# How to config logging in Apache Ignite, sfl4j or log4j

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j, slf4j, ignite

I created spring-boot app with Apache Ignite and want to config logging on server and client side. I followed instructions https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/logging but i got some issues with logging.
For Slf4j

```
<property name="gridLogger">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"/>
</property>
```

on server side if I set `GNITE_QUIET=false` i get

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
```

Ok, I added libs in $IGNITE_HOME/libs/ignite-slf4j/ slf4j-log4j12 and log4j

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.G).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I tried to set -Dlog4j.configurationFile=config/log4j.xml, but it doesn't help.

On server side I managed to set up logging with

```
<property name="gridLogger">
     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j.Log4JLogger">
          <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="log4j.xml"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

but in spring-boot ms I got

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Log4j configuration path was not found: config/log4j.xml
```

It works if I set absolute path

```
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"  value="/home/username/work/ignite/config/log4j.xml"/>
```

but that's not what I need. How do I need to config logs in server/client side correctly?

Answer (score 0):

According your first error, do you use maven? If yes, did you try to include following dependencies to your POM-file?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

"Log4j configuration path was not found" is probably thrown because you placed your config to the folder which is not part of your project. If you don't want to use full path just move it to "resources" folder of the project.